# Append PDF at the available space of another PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, merge, itext, jfreechart

[Viral Patel's tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/itext-tutorial-merge-split-pdf-files-using-itext-jar/) on how to merge and split PDF files is useful. Unfortunately, I need something more than merging the files but appending a PDF to another PDF.

I am generating reports and one component is a graph using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)s. The graph I make is turned into PDF and read again by the merge code. Let us say I have `main.pdf` for the text and tables PDF and `chart.pdf` for the latter.

I am certain that `main.pdf` has an extra space that another figure can fit into which is `chart.pdf` and I want the latter to be scaled and placed there and not bloated in another page.

I have the code below and I can't seem to implement this:

- code to create `chart.pdf`

  ```
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Graphics2D;
  import java.awt.Paint;
  import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;

  import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
  import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
  import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
  import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
  import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
  import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
  import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRenderer;
  import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

  import com.lowagie.text.Document;
  import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.DefaultFontMapper;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

  public class ChartDemo {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          writeChartToPDF(generateBarChart(), 500, 400, "D://chart.pdf");
      }

      public static void writeChartToPDF(JFreeChart chart, int width, int height,
              String fileName) {
          PdfWriter writer = null;
          Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(width, height));

          try {
              writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                      fileName));
              document.open();
              PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();

              PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(width, height);
              Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height,
                      new DefaultFontMapper());
              Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width,
                      height);

              chart.draw(graphics2d, rectangle2d);

              graphics2d.dispose();
              contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          document.close();
      }

      public static JFreeChart generateBarChart() {
          DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
          dataSet.setValue(100, "Population", "2");
          dataSet.setValue(78, "Population", "4");
          dataSet.setValue(62, "Population", "6");
          dataSet.setValue(50, "Population", "8");
          dataSet.setValue(39, "Population", "10");

          JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("", "Team number",
                  "Solved problems (%)", dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                  false, true, false);
          chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

          final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
          plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
          plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(new Color(204, 204, 204));
          plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(new Color(204, 204, 204));

          final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
          rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

          final BarRenderer renderer1 = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
          renderer1.setDrawBarOutline(false);
          renderer1.setShadowVisible(false);
          renderer1.setDrawBarOutline(false);
          renderer1.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.gray);
          renderer1.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.RED);

          return chart;
      }
  }
  ```
- code for merging

  ```
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.List;

  import com.lowagie.text.Document;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
  import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

  public class MergePdf {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
              List<InputStream> pdfs = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
              pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("D:\\main.pdf"));
              pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("D:\\chart.pdf"));
              OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("D:\\merge.pdf");
              MergePdf.concatPDFs(pdfs, output, true);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      public static void concatPDFs(List<InputStream> streamOfPDFFiles,
              OutputStream outputStream, boolean paginate) {

          Document document = new Document();
          try {
              List<InputStream> pdfs = streamOfPDFFiles;
              List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
              int totalPages = 0;
              Iterator<InputStream> iteratorPDFs = pdfs.iterator();

              // Create Readers for the pdfs.
              while (iteratorPDFs.hasNext()) {
                  InputStream pdf = iteratorPDFs.next();
                  PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
                  readers.add(pdfReader);
                  totalPages += pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
              }
              // Create a writer for the outputstream
              PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

              document.open();
              BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                      BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
              PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF
              // data

              PdfImportedPage page;
              int currentPageNumber = 0;
              int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
              Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

              // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
              while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
                  PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

                  // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
                  while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                      document.newPage();
                      pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                      currentPageNumber++;
                      page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader,
                              pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                      cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                      // Code for pagination.
                      if (paginate) {
                          cb.beginText();
                          cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                          cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""
                                  + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520,
                                  5, 0);
                          cb.endText();
                      }
                  }
                  pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
              }
              outputStream.flush();
              document.close();
              outputStream.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              if (document.isOpen())
                  document.close();
              try {
                  if (outputStream != null)
                      outputStream.close();
              } catch (IOException ioe) {
                  ioe.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you please check my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690094/how-to-remove-top-white-space-from-pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer does not directly answer yours but it covers your desired output - the have a `JFreeChart` chart *within* an `iText` PDF.

I saw this amazing, spot-on tutorial on how to make an `iText` PDF with `JFreeChart` inside: [WireLust's "*Creating an iText pdf with embedded JFreeChart*"](http://www.wirelust.com/2008/03/17/creating-an-itext-pdf-with-embedded-jfreechart/). Note that this uses servlets and I modified it to just be a standalone code with the `iText` and `JFreeCharts` to work on.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.DefaultFontMapper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

/**
 * Approaching Pi, Inc. http://www.approachingpi.com
 * <p/>
 * User: tcurran Date: Mar 17, 2008 Time: 2:29:43 AM Desc:
 */
public class PdfChartDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {

        try {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,
                    new FileOutputStream("D:/helix-fossil.pdf"));
            doc.open();

            doc.addProducer();
            doc.addCreator("Jay Leno");
            doc.addTitle("jfreechart pdf");
            doc.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);

            doc.open();

            // add some text to the document
            doc.add(new Phrase(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod "
                            + "tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, "
                            + "quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "
                            + "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu "
                            + "fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, "
                            + "sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."));

            // build up the dataset for the chart
            XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();

            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("XYGraph");
            series.add(1, 1);
            series.add(2, 3);
            series.add(3, 9);
            series.add(4, 11);

            dataset.addSeries(series);

            // set up the chart
            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                    "XY Chart Sample, non default font", // chart title
                    "x-axis", // domain axis label
                    "y-axis", // range axis label
                    dataset, // data
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                    true, // include legend
                    true, // tooltips
                    false // urls
                    );

            // trick to change the default font of the chart
            chart.setTitle(new TextTitle("XY Chart Sample, non default font",
                    new java.awt.Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12)));
            chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
            chart.setBorderPaint(Color.black);
            chart.setBorderStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
            chart.setBorderVisible(true);

            int width = 260;
            int height = 250;

            // get the direct pdf content
            PdfContentByte dc = docWriter.getDirectContent();

            // get a pdf template from the direct content
            PdfTemplate tp = dc.createTemplate(width, height);

            // create an AWT renderer from the pdf template
            Graphics2D g2 = tp.createGraphics(width, height,
                    new DefaultFontMapper());
            Rectangle2D r2D = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
            chart.draw(g2, r2D, null);
            g2.dispose();

            // add the rendered pdf template to the direct content
            // you will have to play around with this because the chart is
            // absolutely positioned.
            // 38 is just a typical left margin
            // docWriter.getVerticalPosition(true) will approximate the position
            // that the content above the chart ended
            dc.addTemplate(tp, 38, docWriter.getVerticalPosition(true) - height);

            doc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

It will produce the same PDF file as with the servlet version.

Comment: This is better than the one I need - less one class! Thank you!

Comment: It would even be better if you changed `com.lowagie` (my name) into `com.itextpdf` to avoid introducing obsolete code into your project (the `com.lowagie` version dates from 2009; plenty of bugs have been fixed since that date).

Comment: Hello Mr. Lowagie, I'm actually using the 4.2.0 version.

Comment: That version is ancient. You shouldn't use it.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, noted sir! Another thing, can my method be improved by eliminating the `PdfContentByte` part wherein I can just do `document.add(myJFreeChart)`?

Comment: @user1685185 Can you please check my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690094/how-to-remove-top-white-space-from-pdf